# drag & drop in collection view and updating indexpath in label

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have issue where I am using two `UICollectionView`, one has data with id, photo and in second collection view I'm appending cell from first `collectionview` and performing drag and drop. in second collection view I have one label which is showing number of appending data in count as I am taking `indexpath.count`, now the issue is whenever I'm dragging and dropping cell I am getting repetition of `indexpath` in label. what should I do?

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == stretchAddedCV{
        return addRoutine.count
    } else {
        return self.arrRoutine.count
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == stretchAddedCV{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AddedRoutineCell", for: indexPath) as! AddedRoutineCell
            let obj = self.addRoutine[indexPath.item]
            
            if let img = obj.thumbnail{
                if let imgUrl = URL.init(string: img) {
                    cell.img.kf.setImage(with: imgUrl, placeholder: PlaceHolderImage)
                }
            }
            let count = indexPath.item + 1
            cell.lblNo.text = "\(count)"
//            if addImage.indices.contains(indexPath.item) {
//                let imageUrl = addImage[indexPath.item]
//                cell.img.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholder: PlaceHolderImage)
//            }
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RoutineListCell", for: indexPath) as! RoutineListCell
            let obj = arrRoutine[indexPath.item]
            cell.configure(with: obj)
            if let title = obj.title {
                cell.lblTitle.text = title
            }
            if let url = obj.thumbnail {
                if let imgUrl = URL.init(string: url) {
                    cell.img.kf.setImage(with: imgUrl, placeholder: PlaceHolderImage)
                }
            }
//            cell.contentView.alpha = 1.0
//            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = !obj.isDisable
            return cell
        }
    }

// drag and Drope Mothed
func collectionView(_ UICollectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard destinationIndexPath.item < addRoutine.count else {
        return
    }
    let temp = self.addRoutine.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
    self.addRoutine.insert(temp, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
    
    self.stretchAddedCV.reloadItems(at: [destinationIndexPath, sourceIndexPath])       
}

//drag and Drope Longe press
@objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.stretchAddedCV.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.stretchAddedCV)) else {
            break
        }
        self.stretchAddedCV.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
    case .changed:
        self.stretchAddedCV.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
    case .ended:
        self.stretchAddedCV.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        self.stretchAddedCV.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `cellForItemAt` function?  Also, perhaps add some screen shots of before and after the move operation so that you can explain the problem more clearly?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have updated cellForItemAt also in code..